# When to store local data in my Windows 8 Metro Application

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, local-storage, tablet

I am a developing a Windows 8 metro application that has a set of settings that the user can specify. I know of a few ways to store these settings in the local storage so they can be restored when the user resumes/re-starts the application.

What I want to know is when should I store this data? Periodically? On Application Close/Crash? When exactly? What are the conventions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any convention / best practice.

The most convenient way is to have all application data in one big class instance, deserialize it at startup and serialize it on close/suspend. This way you need only few lines of code and nearly no logic. A positive side effect is that during operation the app isn't slowed down by loading/saving.

However when the class gets too big, you might experience a noticable increase of startup/shutdown times of your app. This could ultimately lead to being rejected from marektplace. In this case I recommend to save each small bit of information (e.g. a single user setting) instantly, and to load each small bit of information not before it's required.

Answer (score 0):

I would have thought that to some extent that depends on the data.  However, you will need to store the current state of the app on the `Suspending` event (which may also be the close event).

Comment: The data relates to simple app settings according to user preferences, e.g. color of the background, font etc.